# Using state_machine, how can I access event arguments from inside the :if lambda

Tags: ruby, state-machine

I am using the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem to model a card game, and I have a transition condition that requires knowing the event arguments when drawing a card.  Here is some example code.

```
class CardGame
  state_machine do
    before_transition :drawing_card => any, :do => :drawn_card
    event :draw_card
      transition :drawing_card => :end_of_round, :if => lambda {|game|
        # Check goes here, I require knowing which card was taken
        # which is passed as arguments to the event (:ace, :spaces)
      }
    end
  end

  def drawn_card(value, suit)
    # I can access the event arguments in the transition callbacks
  end
end

game = CardGame.new
game.draw_card(:ace, :spades)
```

I am thinking an alternative is to set the card suit and value on the object as variables, but it is much messier than using arguments to the event.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that a state machine probably doesn't belong in your `CardGame` class.  Game state lies elsewhere.  There are four main domain models I can see:

- `Card`
- `Deck`
- `Hand`
- `Game`

A `Game` will have one or more `Decks` (each of 52 `Cards`) and one or more `Hands`. (You might even want to have a `Player` class, where a player has-a `Hand`, your call).

As an example, a `Deck` will probably have a `shuffle!` and a `deal` method.  A `Hand` will have a `play` method.  This is where the rule logic might live.

The `Game` class will primarily consist of a loop such as the following:

```
def run
  deal               
  do 
    play_hands       
    check_for_winner 
  while(playing)
end
```

More devil in the detail of course but you might find this approach more refreshing and easier to test.

Comment: +1 I'd agree with Olly. If I find myself trying to work around limitations of state_machine it probably indicates I am using it for the wrong purpose. A good indicator here is you have a state called :drawing_card which doesn't sound like a state the Game may be in but rather a state a Deck deck may be in which of itself is an indicator you haven't broken the domain down enough.